# Difference Between Wireless & Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

I wanna know what is difference Between Wireless & Wi-Fi ?
Does it same Wireless jamming and Wi-fi jamming ?

Comment: In what context? WiFi (802.11) is a *form* of "wireless". So are the various types of cell phone systems. And amateur radio. (etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wireless** and **Wi-Fi** are used interchangeably for the same concept, but Wi-Fi (often abbreviated to just WiFi) is actually trademarked by the Wi-Fi Alliance non-profit for promoting interoperability with vendors implementing the various 802.11 wireless standards.